# How to display the total sum and calculations from an input in C

Tags: c, geometry

I'm doing an assessment and have to write a short program in C to enter vertices and side size to display perimeter and area of a polygon. 
When the program is terminated, I have to display:

- a. total number of calculations performed
- b. sum of all vertices
- c. sum of all sides sizes
- d. sum of all perimeters
- e. square root of the product of all areas

How is this this done in C? Thanks

I tried storing these in an array and then display them

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    float PI = 3.1415;
    char choice;
    float area, parameter;
    int radius, side, length, width;

    do {
        printf("Please enter a shape(C:Circle, S:Square, R:Rectangle, Q:Quiit> ");
        scanf("%s", &choice);

        switch (choice) {
          case 'C':
            printf("Enter a radius of the circle: ");
            scanf("%d", &radius);
            area = (2 * radius) * PI;
            parameter = 2 * PI * radius;
            printf("The area of the circle is %.02f and parameter is %.02f",
                   area, parameter);
            break;

          case 'S':
            printf("Enter the side of the square: ");
            scanf("%d", &side);
            area = side * side;
            parameter = 4 * side;
            printf("The area of the circle is %.02f and parameter is %.02f",
                   area, parameter);
            break;

          case 'R':
            printf("Enter the width of the rectangle: ");
            scanf("%d", &width);
            printf("Enter the length of the rectangle: ");
            scanf("%d", &length);
            area = length * width;
            parameter = (2 * length) + (2 * width);
            printf("The area of the circle is %.02f and parameter is %.02f",
                   area, parameter);
            break;

          case 'Q':
            printf ("Thank and bye");
            break;

          default:
            printf ("Invalid input");
        }
        return 0;
    } while (choice != 'Q');
}
```

I expect that this is done through an array, but I'm unsure how arrays work.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could make clear what the issue is. As it stands, you've just given us code and "how?". Please attach the errors or unexpected behaviour you are facing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some remarks on the current code

Having

> ```
>  char choice;
>  ...
>  scanf ("%s", &choice);
> ```

you write at least one character out of *choice* to put the null character, the behavior is undefined

You want to enter a character do

```
scanf (" %c", &choice);
```

the space before `%s` allowing to bypass the separators (newline / space)

Why the `return 0;` if you want to loop up to 'Q' ? Remove it.

Add newline at the end of all the prints giving a result to separate it with the question after (or of course replace "Please enter a shape..." by "\nPlease enter a shape..." to not have it on the same line of the previous print)

I encourage you to check something valid is enter through the *scanf*, else you cannot know if for instance an integer was enter for `scanf("%d", &radius);`, so check *scanf* returns 1

> I expect that this is done through an array, but I'm unsure how arrays work.

You do not need array(s), for 'a' 'b' 'c' and 'd' the sums can be updated each time, for 'e' update the product each time then at the end do the *square*

Anyway if you prefer to memorize you need several arrays, one for each topic, you have two solutions :

- you use statically sized arrays, and in that case you have to limit the number of inputs to not go out of it
- you use dynamic array using *malloc* then *realloc* to increase their size

then at the end ('Q') you compute the needed value from the arrays content

---

For instance managing 'a' and 'e' in the two ways depending on the preprocessor identifier ARRAYS :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#ifdef ARRAYS
typedef struct Vector {
  float * values;
  size_t nValues;
} Vector;

// initialize the array, must be called because to add values
void init(Vector * v)
{
  v->values = malloc(0);
  v->nValues = 0;
}

// a a new value into the vector
void add(Vector * v, float f)
{
  v->values = realloc(v->values, (++v->nValues) * sizeof(float));
  v->values[v->nValues - 1] = f;
}

// print the content of the array
void pr(Vector * v, const char * what)
{
  printf("there are %d %s :", v->nValues, what);
  for (size_t i = 0; i != v->nValues; ++i)
    printf(" %.02f", v->values[i]);
  putchar('\n');
}
#endif

int main ()
{
  float PI = 3.1415;
  char choice;
  float area, parameter;
  int radius, side, length, width;
#ifdef ARRAYS
  Vector calculations, areas;

  init(&calculations);
  init(&areas);
#else
  int calcNumber = 0;
  float prodAreas = 1;
#endif

  do {
    printf("Please enter a shape(C:Circle, S:Square, R:Rectangle, Q:Quit> ");
    scanf (" %c", &choice);

    switch (choice) {
    case 'C':
      printf ("Enter a radius of the circle: ");
      if (scanf ("%d", &radius) != 1) {
        puts("invalid value");
        return -1;
      }
      area = (2 * radius) * PI;
      parameter = 2 * PI * radius;
      printf ("The area of the circle is %.02f and parameter is %.02f\n",
              area, parameter);
#ifdef ARRAYS
      add(&calculations, area);
      add(&areas, area);
      add(&calculations, parameter);
#else
      calcNumber += 2;
      prodAreas *= area;
#endif
      break;

    case 'S':
      printf ("Enter the side of the square: ");
      if (scanf ("%d", &side) != 1) {
        puts("invalid value");
        return -1;
      }
      area = side * side;
      parameter = 4 * side;
      printf ("The area of the circle is %.02f and parameter is %.02f\n",
              area, parameter);
#ifdef ARRAYS
      add(&calculations, area);
      add(&areas, area);
      add(&calculations, parameter);
#else
      calcNumber += 2;
      prodAreas *= area;
#endif
      break;

    case 'R':
      printf ("Enter the width of the rectangle: ");
     if ( scanf ("%d", &width) != 1) {
        puts("invalid value");
        return -1;
      }
      printf ("Enter the length of the rectangle: ");
      if (scanf ("%d", &length) != 1) {
        puts("invalid value");
        return -1;
      }
      area = length * width;
      parameter = (2 * length) + (2 * width);
      printf ("The area of the circle is %.02f and parameter is %.02f\n",
              area, parameter);
#ifdef ARRAYS
      add(&calculations, area);
      add(&areas, area);
      add(&calculations, parameter);
#else
      calcNumber += 2;
      prodAreas *= area;
#endif
      break;

    case 'Q':
      puts ("Thank and bye");
      break;

    default:
      puts ("Invalid input");
    }
  } while (choice != 'Q');

#ifdef ARRAYS
  pr(&calculations, "calculations");

  pr(&areas, "areas");

  float e = 1;

  for (size_t i = 0; i != areas.nValues; ++i)
    e *= areas.values[i];
  printf("square root of the product of all areas : %.02f\n", sqrt(e));
#else
  printf("there are %d calculations\n", calcNumber);
  printf("square root of the product of all areas : %.02f\n", sqrt(prodAreas));
#endif

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution using arrays :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -DARRAYS -pedantic -Wall  -Wextra c.c -lm
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Please enter a shape(C:Circle, S:Square, R:Rectangle, Q:Quit> C
Enter a radius of the circle: 1
The area of the circle is 6.28 and parameter is 6.28
Please enter a shape(C:Circle, S:Square, R:Rectangle, Q:Quit> S
Enter the side of the square: 1
The area of the circle is 1.00 and parameter is 4.00
Please enter a shape(C:Circle, S:Square, R:Rectangle, Q:Quit> Q
Thank and bye
there are 4 calculations : 6.28 6.28 1.00 4.00
there are 2 areas : 6.28 1.00
square root of the product of all areas : 2.51
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Compilation and execution without arrays :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall  -Wextra c.c -lm
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Please enter a shape(C:Circle, S:Square, R:Rectangle, Q:Quit> C
Enter a radius of the circle: 1
The area of the circle is 6.28 and parameter is 6.28
Please enter a shape(C:Circle, S:Square, R:Rectangle, Q:Quit> S
Enter the side of the square: 1
The area of the circle is 1.00 and parameter is 4.00
Please enter a shape(C:Circle, S:Square, R:Rectangle, Q:Quit> Q
Thank and bye
there are 4 calculations
square root of the product of all areas : 2.51
```

I let you doing for 'b' 'c' and 'd'